# Why is my computer slow (usually on startup) even though Task Manager doesn't show anything terrible?

Tags: task-manager, windows-11, acer-aspire, lag

For the past few months, my computer has been running slow on startup. This only happens every now and then, and it seems completely random. It sometimes goes away for a week or two, but then comes back every other day for a long time. I've tried every solution I can find. I thought maybe it was Windows Security, but I don't think so. I thought it was a memory leak - don't think so. My computer was being laggy again today, so I decided finally to ask a question which specifically had my problems. My task manager looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lqbb.png) and my computer will not load anything. For example, I play Geometry Dash. This morning, I booted my computer up (which took longer than usual, so I think this issue begins immediately upon startup) and Geometry Dash crashed. I tried again, and a level that I can usually run very, very easily lagged. All of this happened while Task Manager looked like the picture. At first, this issue seemed to take half an hour before it went away - but it's now been four hours since the issue began today and it's still happening. I've tried everything I can possibly think of short of wiping my computer (which I might do in a week or so, and make a new account.) I have all startup programs disabled. Windows Security shouldn't be running. Are there any things that may be causing this problem? If so, how would I fix them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

This could be because of various reasons :

1. **Virus, Rootkits... etc. :** These can work in the background and take your RAM or CPU percentages. More over if your system is effected by a rootkit, it won't register in the task manger.
2. **Windows Updates :** This could be another reason for your high resource consumptions. As you said it happens in intervals.
3. **3rd Party Softwares :** There could be other 3rd party softwares running in background, which would use your resources.
4. **Problematic Hard Disk :** If your hard disk has many bad sectors, it would cause your system to run slow or even it may crush the system or some software to crush.
5. **Your own System Resources :** The problem could also be a result of your own System Resources be less or not enough to handle Windows 11 along with the applications you run on the system.

How to fix :

1. Install a good Anti Virus software.
2. If that do not fix the problem, you could format the whole system once **(take backup before)**.
3. You could even go back to Windows 10. No need to fear, windows 10 is still very much active and gets regular updates. Going back to windows 10, would make the host windows consume less resources and thus more free resources to use.
4. Change the hard disk. Please try to buy a new hard disk form a reputed and reliable vendor.
5. Update the System Resources. Like use a better processor or increase RAM or use a better Graphics Card.

**More Importantly**: Use a GOOD, RELIABLE **Anti Virus Software** to protect the system. Always scan any devices which you connect to the system. And don't use open public Wi-Fi.